# TCP Movement Lag

Tags: networking, tcp, xna

I'm working on a small multiplayer 2D XNA Game using TCP. My issue is that when more than 2 people connect everyone starts to lag out. Currently for every new x,y position the player has it sends it as a packet to the server to broadacast to every other player connected on the network. This ultimately sends a massive amount of packets which I think causes the issue I'm having.

Is it normal to send every x,y coordinate to every player or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending every packet, you should only send packets when the player changes direction, by either jumping, or moving left/right. The clients should handle gravity and collision as normal, while the server validates it.

When they move, send a packet containing:

1. **Their movement vector** (This should be a small Vector2 or Point that is either `-1`, `0`, or `1` on each axis. `-1` X means they are moving left, `0` means no movement, and `1` means right movement)

   You should implement this client side already if you have not (Don't just add X to the velocity when you move, assign it to a movement variable to use later.

   Ex:

   `if (KeyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) { Movement.X = -1 }
    ...
    Velocity += Movement * Speed`
2. **Their current position.** Send the players current position (The serverside and validated one) to all other players, to make sure their position matches (It may be off due to small changes)
3. **Their current velocity.** The velocity of the player should have changed when the movement changed, since they are now going a different direction. Send the velocity along with the position.

Overall, only when a player moves (Ex: Stops holding the left key or presses the jump key) and NOT every frame, send the `movement` (Direction you are going based on keyboard input), `position`, and `velocity`.

Once you have this completed, you may want to add interpolation, which will smooth the movements between updates and make it look less jerky.

Comment: So as long as theres an input I should have it continously send a packet containing that information?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, not continously, but ONLY if the player changes direction or stops moving. For example, if I am pressing left to move left, and I stop pressing it, then I send a packet to tell the server and other clients that I have STOPED moving. If I press right to move right, then I tell the server and clients that I have started to move right (After the server validates it of course)

Comment: Oh okay, so instead of having it so that when you hold down the left key it sends a packet everytime a player moves x , y in any amount on the screen (This is what I'm doing now), it just sends say 2 packets one to say the player has started to move in this direction and then another packet to tell the server that the player as stopped moving.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The client will receive the `movement`, so it knows to keep moving that direction, even after the packet.

Comment: Cheers, I will go and make the changes and hopefully it will resolve my issue. I will let you know :)

Comment: and from this you can see why lots of FPS games have players walk continuously into walls when their connection times out

Comment: Yeah, also why it happens with bad connections in general, if the packet to stop moving is dropped it will cause issues.